# How to insert subtotals in an Excel footer?

Tags: excel

How I can include subtotals amounts at the bottom/footer of each page of an excel sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)?  If so, you'll find this to be an easy task.

Reading this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/273028 we learn that all one has to do to have a dynamically updated footer is something like this:

```
Sub UpdateFooter()
   ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Leftfooter = Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

...which inserts the value in cell A1 into the left side of the page footer.